# ¿Una forma mejor de eliminar todas las apariciones de un elemento en una lista?

Tags: lista, pascal

Tengo un procedimiento que resuelve lo que quiero: recibe una lista y un número n y elimina todas las apariciones de n dentro de la misma.
Sin embargo es bastante horrible el código y quería saber cómo puedo optimizarlo (o al menos saber que se puede mejorar) para que haga lo mismo pero sea más claro.

Este es el código:

```
procedure eliminar(var lista_numeros : lista; n : integer);
var
    actual, anterior : lista;
begin
    actual := lista_numeros;
    while(actual <> nil) do begin
        if(actual^.datos = n) then begin
            if(actual = lista_numeros) then begin
                lista_numeros := lista_numeros^.sig
                dispose(actual);
                actual := lista_numeros;
            end
            else begin
                anterior^.sig := actual^.sig;
                dispose(actual);
                actual := anterior^.sig;
            end;
        end
        else begin
            anterior := actual;
            actual := actual^.sig;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: El código no es horrible, de hecho, luce bastante bien. Yo haría algunas mejoras a la indentación y estilo, pero no veo nada fuera de eso que haga falta para hacerlo óptimo o más claro.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo como consejo genérico, cuando hay que recorrer una lista, array o similar para eliminar elementos, suele ser más sencillo (si no hay ninguna condición que lo impida) realizar el recorrido *desde el final al principio*.

La razón es sencilla, cuando lo hacemos del inicio al final y eliminamos elementos, hay determinadas circunstancias que pueden cambiar y que nos afectan:

- Número total de elementos
- Elementos restantes
- ...

Si lo piensas bien, al hacer el recorrido desde el final al principio, algunas de estas situaciones no son tan problemáticas.

**NOTA:** Depende mucho de la estructura que estés utilizando. Aquí no comentas de qué tipo es `lista`, pero suele ser algo genérico.

Comment: Por lo que veo es una lista enlazada, no doblemente enlazada, con lo cual el recorrido se puede hacer en una sola dirección. Pero, aún cundo fuera doblemente enlazada, dado el código de ejemplo de la pregunta, no veo una mejora intrínseca en hacer el recorrido a la inversa. Quizás debieras agregar algo de código para explicarte mejor. Un saludo cordial Germán, siempre es un gusto verte por aquí! :)